# JQuery - resize div on click

Tags: jquery

When I click on arrow-down image it resizes comment div to 400px and adds class arrow-up (shows different image). When i click on arrow-up image instead of going up 320px it goes down 320px again. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('.arrow-down').click(function() {
            $('.comment').animate({height: '+=320px'}, 1000);   
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
        $(this).addClass('arrow-up');
    });

    $('.arrow-up').click(function() {
            $('.comment').animate({height: '-=320px'}, 1000);   
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-up');
        $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
    });
```

Comment: You need to use delegated event handlers as you're changing the classes on the elements after the page has loaded

Comment: Search for accordion or collapsible components. P.s: better not to animate divs using jquery but use css instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow-down', function(event) {
    $('.comment').animate({height: '+=320px'}, 1000);
    $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    $(this).addClass('arrow-up');
});
$(document).on('click', '.arrow-up', function(event) {
    $('.comment').animate({height: '-=320px'}, 1000);
    $(this).removeClass('arrow-up');
    $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegated event handlers as you're changing the classes on the elements after the page has loaded:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.arrow-down', function() {
  $('.comment').animate({ height: '+=320px' }, 1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
}).on('click', '.arrow-up', function() {
  $('.comment').animate({ height: '-=320px' }, 1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
});
```

```css
.comment {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">This is a comment...</div>
<div class="arrow-down">Click me</div>
```